# About the Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$. Prove that : $E[X^n] = n!/\lambda n$

The hint in (Fundamentals of probability) gives the hint use the Moment Generating Function, but I can't see how I should use that to prove that this is the respective expression that follows.

Comment: Can you at least show us to what formula you get ?

Comment: I found that the MGF of an exponential random variable = λ/ (λ-t), and I have taken the derivative of it a few times now and found the expression is true. However this is no proof, just a few examples.

Comment: You mean  $λn$ or $λ^n$ in the denominator?

Answer (score 4):

The MGF of the exponential distribution is given by \begin{align}M_X(t)&=\frac{λ}{λ-t}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{λ}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{t}{λ}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}\cdot\frac{n!}{λ^n}\end{align} by the formula of the geometric series, for $|t/λ|<1$. Now compare the above expression with the definition of the MGF $$M_X(t)=\mathbb E\left[e^{tX}\right]=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nX^n}{n!}\right]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}\mathbb E[X^n]$$

Comment: Thanks: But in this proof, is it that when you take the expected value of this expression to n-th power of X, that the summation and that first term cancel out?

Comment: @JuniorEshun No, this is not the case. By the way, I asked you a question in the comments as well, but got no answer...

Comment: I replied, the question has been answered by you and martini, it's clear now! 2 different but clear proofs of this formula.

Answer (score 4):

The MGF is $m(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}$. We state, that the $n$-th derivative is 
$$ m^{(n)}(t) =  n!\frac{\lambda}{(\lambda - t)^{n+1}}. $$
This is true for $n=0$, if it is true for $n$, we get
\begin{align*}
   m^{(n+1)}(t) &= \frac{\lambda}{-(\lambda - t)}^{n+2}\cdot \bigl(-(n+1)\bigr) \\
        &= (n+1)! \frac{\lambda}{(\lambda-t)^{n+2}} 
\end{align*}
Therefore 
$$ \mathbf E[X^n] = m^{(n)}(0) = \frac{n!}{\lambda^{n}} $$